# How do I write queries for data in tables that already contain relationships?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

I have a table called `PersonsTable`:

```
   PersonID  FirstName   Surname  Age
   ----------------------------------
    1         Hansen      Ola      30
    2         Svendson    Tove     23
    3         Pettersen   Kari     20
```

I also have a table called `OrdersTable`:

```
OrderID OrderNumber PersonID
----------------------------
1               77895   3
2               44678   3
3               22456   2
4               24562   1
```

- The `PersonID` column in the `PersonsTable` table is the PRIMARY
  KEY.
- The `PersonID` column in the `OrdersTable` table is a foreign key.

How do I write a query that returns the `FirstName` and the `OrderNumber` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OT.OrderNumber,PT.FirstName    
FROM OrdersTable AS OT
JOIN PersonsTable AS PT ON OT.PersonID=PT.PersonID
```

Comment: Since the query above works without creating a relationship between columns, is there a need to create relationships between columns?.

Comment: I initially thought if we created relationships between columns then there would be no need for JOINS. I'm not questioning your answer here, I'm just trying to understand how JOINS and relationships work.

Comment: JOIN can be done without any foreign keys between tables. JOIN only compares values from the left side to values from the right side. But then we come to question about data integrity. Without foreign key it will be possible to assign order to the person absent in the PersonsTable and very often it is not OK

Comment: @WaliBadawi: yes - the query *would* work without the foreign key relationship. The FK **however** ensures **data integrity**, in that you cannot insert a row into the `OrdersTable` with a `PersonID` that doesn't already exist in `PersonsTable` - that's the **main purpose** of the FK constraint - ensure referential data integrity

Comment: Okay I now understand. That makes sense. Thank you for clarifying this for me.